# JSON to a JSON array Cannot deserialize the current JSON object in MVC5

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code to fetch data from Json object

```
 System.Console.WriteLine("Error Create Order: {0} {1}", postOrderResult.StatusCode, postOrderResult.ReasonPhrase);
                var orderResults = postOrderResult.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<OrderResult>>().Result;
```

But its returning error

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ABCS.WebApi.Models.OrderResult]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path 'Message', line 1, position 11.

Please help

Comment: What are you trying to deserialize? What is your JSON object? What is `OrderResult`? Please, provide more information. Exceptions message and one line of code is not enough.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I am getting Json responds from a WEBAPI and postOrderResult is the JsonData which i am trying deserialise into OrderResult model

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I tried something like this now but returning the same error var jsonString = postOrderResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    jsonString.Wait();
                    orderResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OrderResult>>(jsonString.Result);

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Another try is List<OrderResult> orderResults = (List<OrderResult>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString.Result, typeof(List<OrderResult>));

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are passing a simple JSON object while your data type is expecting for an array of JSON objects.

Try encasing your current JSON data between "[" and "]"